# Sqlalchemy AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

**Situation**

Users make purchases, which are stored as transactions in 3 different tables (depending on the type). I need to calculate total amount of transactions/purchases of female and male users, so I need to look into all 3 tables.

For this I created a `@property` in the User table:

```
@property
def count_credits_purchases(self):
    trans = object_session(self).query(Transaction_1).filter(Transaction_1.type == "credits").with_parent(self).count()
    trans_vk = object_session(self).query(Transaction_2).filter(Transaction_2.type == "credits").with_parent(self).count()
    trans_stripe = object_session(self).query(Transaction_3).filter(Transaction_3.type == "credits").with_parent(self).count()
    value = trans + trans_vk + trans_stripe
    return int(value)
```

I am trying to calculate the total amount of purchases by using sqlalchemy `func.sum()`:

```
total_purchases_males_credits = db_session.query(func.sum(Users.count_credits_purchases))
.filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == "1")
.scalar()
```

**Problem**

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

The translate method is a string method, what is happening here? I definitely return an integer in `count_credits_purchases`.

I made a test and checking the value per user is always correct:

```
all_users = db_session.query(Users).limit(200)
for user in all_users:
    print (user.count_credits_purchases) # gives correct result
```

I could make a variable and calculate it in the loop, but it is super unefficient and would need probably 1 hour if there are 50k users. I need to understand how to work with the `@property` attribute

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `hybrid_property`?

Comment: @vishes_shell I am currently experimenting with column_property, next will be hybrid_property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution here is probably using `@hybrid_property` but I had problems to make it work.

I came up with a completely different solution, using a classical method. This was super fast and so far I dont see any downsides:

```
# Normal method to calculate | Best case would probably be @hybrid_method
def count_credits_purchases(self, start_date, end_date, gender):
    trans = db_session.query(Transaction_1).filter(Transaction_1.type == "credits", Transaction_1.user_id == Users.id).filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == gender).count()
    trans_vk = db_session.query(Transaction_2).filter(Transaction_2.type == "credits", Transaction_2.user_id == Users.id).filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == gender).count()
    trans_stripe = db_session.query(Transaction_3).filter(Transaction_3.type == "credits", Transaction_3.user_id == Users.id).filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == gender).count()
    value = trans + trans_vk + trans_stripe
    return value
```

Call in python:

```
total_purchases_males_credits = Users().count_credits_purchases(start_date, end_date, "1")
```

I would still like to know how good ths approach is compared to hybrid_property?

**EDIT:**

Its also possible to use `@hybrid_method`:

```
@hybrid_method
def count_credits_purchases(self, start_date, end_date, gender):
    trans = db_session.query(Transaction_1).filter(Transaction_1.type == "credits", Transaction_1.user_id == Users.id).filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == gender).count()
    trans_vk = db_session.query(Transaction_2).filter(Transaction_2.type == "credits", Transaction_2.user_id == Users.id).filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == gender).count()
    trans_stripe = db_session.query(Transaction_3).filter(Transaction_3.type == "credits", Transaction_3.user_id == Users.id).filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == gender).count()
    value = trans + trans_vk + trans_stripe
    return value
```

And use it:

```
total_purchases_males_credits = db_session.query(func.sum(Users.count_credits_purchases(start_date, end_date, "1"))).scalar()
```

Comment: The problem is pretty much specific (so i cannot dive in it completely), and as well it works for you, and is fast enough, then it is a _problem solver_. Good work!

Answer (score 2):

As the docs [*Using Descriptors and Hybrids*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#using-descriptors-and-hybrids) says you should be using [`hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid) to be able to use them in your queries.

Take a look at example in docs:

> ```
> class EmailAddress(Base):
>     __tablename__ = 'email_address'
>
>     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>
>     # name the attribute with an underscore,
>     # different from the column name
>     _email = Column("email", String)
>
>     # then create an ".email" attribute
>     # to get/set "._email"
>     @property
>     def email(self):
>         return self._email
> ```
>
> While our `EmailAddress` object will shuttle the value through the email descriptor and into the _email mapped attribute, the class level `EmailAddress.email` attribute does not have the usual expression semantics usable with Query. To provide these, we instead use the `hybrid` extension

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Already two people telling me to try @hybrid_property. I was currently trying to use column_property but I switch to hybrid now. It doesn't work right of the bat: `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.DeclarativeMeta' is not mapped; was a class (stats_models.Users) supplied where an instance was required?` But I try to figure it out, thanks

Comment: If you have the time, check my answer please. Is the normal method a viable solution here? I have problems to make hybrid_method work.